# Is the origin itself plus a line that doesn't go through the origin considered a linear subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's focus on R2 to make it easy.    A line that doesn't go through the origin isn't considered a linear subspace or a vector .
My question is, if I add artificially the origin.  And construct a subgroup containing both a line and the origin  (0,0). Will that BE considered a subspace together?

Answer (score 3):

Lines that don't pass through the origin are not closed under addition. Consider the line given by $y=x+1$. It contains the points $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$, but their sum is $(3,5)$, which is not on the given line.

There are similar problems with closure under scalar multiplication. It's not just about containing the origin; linearity means much more than that.

Comment: Well, if we claim that, then it's hard to argue than any line isn't "through the origin", because by that non-standard definition, it would contain the zero vector.

Comment: Your teacher's interpretation is at variance with..... every linear algebra text I've seen.

Comment: So to summarize it.  The correct definition of a line is : the collection of all vectors getting from the origin and ending on the line?

Comment: Yes, a point on the plane is identified with the vector from the origin to that point.

Comment: Lol.  Thx.    So if you say he is wrong then it's just a waste of time.   I thought he might have been right but if not then.  Never mind.  Thx for your informative answer.

Answer (score 2):

Pick any point on the line. If you scale the point by $2$, does it still belong in your set?